# Prompt Download of Text File to User - API Controller C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, download

So I am trying to prompt a download of a text file located on the server to the User's machine. I have been searching and failing for a few hours and am now hoping I can get some help from asking here.

The function is in an ApiController.

```
public class LogViewerController : ApiController
```

Here is the function called.

```
public void Get()
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"C:\TestDocument.txt";

            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="Test");

            context.Response.WriteFile(path);

            context.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

I want it to grab the file at the path, then ask the User if they want to download/save the file. However, this isn't happening. The file is being read, but the output is just printing out into '#textField' instead of downloading.

Here is the Javascript/ajax side:

```
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@ViewBag.servicesUrl/LogViewer',
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success: function (retdata) {
            $('#textField').html(retdata);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //
        },
    });
```

I'm completely stumped as to what is causing the issue. Is it something to do with it being in a Get?

Please let me know if I need to add anything to clarify, this is my first time asking a question. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use AJAX for a file download, just provide a link to a controller route/url that will run the same basic server code you already have.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm quite new to Web API and I'm not entirely sure what you mean. How do I "provide a link to the controller" that isn't in AJAX? It's all I've done it in so far haha. Sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: No AJAX, just a link: `<a href="/whatever/path/to/log">Download</a>`  Have the url mapped to an MVC controller action.